# How to access claims from HttpContext in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

Using below code to signIn with custom claims and it's working fine.

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var claims = await _claimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        claims.Identities.First().AddClaims(new[]
        {
            new Claim("xxx", "111"),
            new Claim("yyy", "222")
        });

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claims);
    }
```

but when trying to access using HttpContext in service like below

```
var claims = HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.ToList();
```

it returns 0 claims.

Please help.

Comment: At what point is this service used? Is this in middleware? Make sure that `app.UseAuthentication()` takes place before the service is used.

Comment: @Ruard using in service. Also moved services.AddAuthentication above services but same result

Comment: I mean the order in `Configure`, e.g. `app.UseMyMiddlewareThatCallsService(); app.UseAuthentication();`. Which should be the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Ruard It works :). Please add your message as Answer so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: I'm glad it works now. I've added an answer.

Comment: Claims are accessible in case of  - > Run the App 1. Login -> Access Claims | but not in case of ->  1. Logout -> Login -> Now Claims count is 0

Comment: if  HttpContext.User = claims; before HttpContext.SignInAsync method then it's working fine. Even I tried SignInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync method is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally here is working code.*

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnSignedIn = (context) =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

My assumption was that the claims were missing due to the order of the statements that build the pipeline.

In `Configure` you can insert middleware to the pipeline. When inserting middleware, the order is important, unlike in `ConfigureServices` where it's not.

So when a service is used in middleware that uses the claims before the user is authenticated, then the claims are not available yet, e.g.:

```
app.UseMyMiddlewareThatCallsService(); 
app.UseAuthentication();
```

But when the order is changed, the claims are.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMyMiddlewareThatCallsService();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the schema, the authentication handler may not update `HttpContext.User` by default.

For example, the cookie authentication handler does not sign the current user in, instead, it [only generates authentication ticket and sets it to response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-an-authentication-cookie).

> `SignInAsync` creates an encrypted cookie and adds it to the current response. If AuthenticationScheme isn't specified, the default scheme is used.

If you are using cookie authentication, you could handle [`CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnSignedIn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onsignedin?view=aspnetcore-3.1) event to update `HttpContext.User`:

```
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    opt =>
    {
        opt.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnSignedIn = async ctx =>
            {
                ctx.HttpContext.User = ctx.Principal;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I tried your approach as well but event is not getting called.

Comment: @Ravi The event in answer is an example when you use Cookie authentication. What authentication schema are you using?

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

Comment: @Ravi For testing purpose, do you want to add `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(...)` from my answer and try `await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claims);`

Comment: yes like this

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnSignedIn = async ctx =>
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => 
                        {
                            ctx.HttpContext.User = ctx.Principal;
                        });
                    }
                };
            });

Comment: @Ravi No, `AddCookie` must have a name, which matches the name you passed into `SignInAsync`.  Like my answer did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212686/discussion-between-ravi-and-weichch).

Comment: you answer gives clue to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (access token in header or query parameter)
{
    // Set the claims like in the Account/Login action from the interactive login form
    var claims = ...;
    // Local helper method, is used in other places, too
    var claimsIdentity = await SignInAsync(httpContext, claims, false);
    // Set user for the current request
    // This works in that it's in User.Identity, but the auth events won't fire
    httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
}
```